# How to debug HTTP requests being executed twice by Apache2?

Tags: apache, request, server

My issue is the following: **when I make a HTML request to my server (via Firefox for instance), *sometimes* this request is handled twice by said server.**

---

I do not know why this happens **only sometimes**, but this does **NOT** seem to depend of the following:

- Web browser
- Type of request (GET, POST, etc.)
- Machine sending the request (behind a proxy or not)

---

Here are for instance the Apache2 logs for a *single* request by the client (the change in the HTTP code between the two request is normal, since the first execution of the request changes a state, which leads to the second execution returning in error) :

```
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined

<IP address> - - [17/Dec/2015:10:01:10 +0100] "GET <url> HTTP/1.1" 204 2215 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:42.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/42.0"
<IP address> - - [17/Dec/2015:10:01:10 +0100] "GET <url> HTTP/1.1" 404 13250 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:42.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/42.0"
```

And here is the site Apache2 configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        Servername <Server Name>

        DocumentRoot /var/www/<directory>
        <Directory /var/www/<directory> >
                Options -Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride all
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>

        php_flag   xdebug.remote_enable on
        php_flag   xdebug.default_enable on
        php_flag   xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger on

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        LogLevel warn
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Can you see something wrong with the configuration? Or else give me some pointers to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You may use an addon for Firefox, which shows the HTTP Headers (e.g. Live HTTP Headers). Checking the request/response headers, you may see whats going on in the background.